# WordPress menus - automatically generate

Tags: menus, scripts, automation

I want to automatically generate some menu items using a script (i.e. using `wp_update_nav_menu_item`).

This would usually be a one-off event but I might want to repeat it if the menu items need re-generating.

I guess I could write the script then manually include it in `functions.php` when I want it to run. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WP database (via proper methods) to store a 'is this the first run' flag?

Then just conditionally execute.

1. check for flag in wp db
2. if exist do nothing
3. if not exist
4. create me my menus dag nammit
5. remember to set flag for next round so its only done once

Something like that?

If you need to regenerate then just flip the flag from within the code that decides if the menus need regenerating.